# Show an array of objects on List

Tags: swift, swiftui

**Array of Tuples**

```
var cardData = [

   Card(deck: "A", message: "Hello" ),
   Card(deck: "B", message: "Bye" )
   Card(deck: "B", message: "Good morning" )

]
```

**NavigationView** - I want to show the card of deck "B" only, so I add the if statement. But it shows an empty row on the table view which before the first row of deck "B". How can I fix this bug. Thank you!

```
        NavigationView {
            List(cardData) { item in

                //Want to filter 
                if item.deck == "B" {

                    NavigationLink(destination:
                        Text("Details")
                    ){
                        Text(item.deck)
                        Text(item.message)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Please provide an image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution is to use the `filter` function together with `ForEach`

```
List {
    ForEach(cardData.filter {$0.deck == "B"}) { item in
```

or just `ForEach` with an `if`

```
List {
    ForEach(cardData) { item in
        if (item.deck == "B") {
```

Answer (score 1):

What you call an empty row is in fact a `NavidationBar`. I have added a title to your view to show that. The best way to make sure you are only showing deck "B" is to apply the filtering to the `Array` as you pass it into `List`. An `Array` you pass into `List` or `ForEach` needs to either contain items that are `Identifiable` or you have to explicitly provide which property should be used as an `id`.

```
 NavigationView {
     List(cardData.filter{ $0.deck == "B" }, id:  \.message) { card in
         NavigationLink(destination: Text("Details")) {
             Text(card.deck)
             Text(card.message)
         }
     }
     .navigationBarTitle("Deck B")
 }
```